# How to get single value from .xml

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have some xml or excel I want to loop through this document in InDesign script and insert values on defined places
this is excel or xml
[image]
[image]

this I want to get
[image]

I don't have so much scripting experiences so I can only this piece of code

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var myFile = File("~/Desktop/test.xml");
var textExcel = doc.textFrames.add();
textExcel.geometricBounds = [50, 80, 10, 150];
textExcel.place(myFile);
```

but now how I can get a single value? for example in indesign template first paragraph should look like table --> lorem--> 150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the possible solution:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// get a text from the XLSX file
var inputFile = File("d:/table.xlsx");
var temp_frame = doc.textFrames.add();
temp_frame.place(inputFile);
var text = temp_frame.parentStory.contents;
temp_frame.remove();

// make a table from the text
var rows = text.split('\r');
var table = [];
for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) table.push(rows[i].split('\t'));

// loop through the table and make the cards
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    var title       = table[i][0];
    var description = table[i][1];
    var price       = table[i][2];

    var card = make_card(title, description, price);

    // move the card to some places
    card.move([10,10]);
    card.move(undefined, [i*75, 0]);
}

// the function to create and return a card
function make_card(title, description, price) {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    var title_frame = doc.textFrames.add();
    title_frame.geometricBounds = [20, 80, 30, 150];
    title_frame.contents = title;

    var description_frame = doc.textFrames.add();
    description_frame.geometricBounds = [30, 80, 80, 150];
    description_frame.contents = description;

    var price_frame = doc.textFrames.add();
    price_frame.geometricBounds = [80, 80, 100, 150];
    price_frame.contents = price;

    // apply styles to the texts in the card
    apply_style('title', title_frame);
    apply_style('description', description_frame);
    apply_style('price', price_frame);

    var group = doc.groups.add([title_frame, description_frame, price_frame]);
    return group;
}

function apply_style(style_name, frame) {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    try {
        var style = doc.paragraphStyles.itemByName(style_name);
        frame.paragraphs.everyItem().appliedParagraphStyle = style;
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

This is the XLSX table:

[image]

Here is the result layout (3 cards):

[image]

It creates cards from XLSX file (applies the styles to the texts inside cards, why not?) and put them on the page of the current document.

Comment: and how it would work if there is more then 3 items in excel otherwise it go out of the page.

Comment: It can be done many ways. Depends on what you have and what you want to get. Sometimes it makes sense: one card per page. Or you can make a page with custom size, something like 10 cards in one row. Or you can keep pages with standard size and make a grid of cards on every pages, say 2x3 or 3x4 cards per page. Etc. It would be different implementations for every case.

Comment: yes I know it can be done by many ways. But I didn't get how to work with scripting for Indesign. Where did you learn it? For example I for me it has logic to add in for loop this piece of code  /*      if(i > 2){
        card.move([20,10]);
        card.move(undefined, [i*75, 20]);
    }  */   and I except that it start in next line 20 down but it doesn't and it is also not smart to always get an index if in excel is 200 rows

Comment: I see your new question. It looks like you want to make a grids of cards on every page. I will try to answer there. It's hard to show a code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this with xpath and Document.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

You create a new Document with the xml and you evaluate a xPath.